# Where can I find a free SDK for C#?

Tags: c#

I need a free and recent SDK for use with C#. I will work first in 2D games with visual effects. Thanks for now.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: XNA is free, you should use that

Comment: Thanks Douglas, but i was searching one more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your pick, all of these use C#. I recommend the first as I believe it to be the easiest one to get started with, especially for 2D graphics:

- [Microsoft XNA](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/) - Built on top of DirectX9. Very user friendly and game oriented.
- [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) - An OpenGL C# wrapper.
- [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) - A DirectX C# wrapper.
- [SharpDX](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/) - Another DirectX C# wrapper.